# Arduino Nano Doesn't Upload Any Code After Connecting It In Reverse (Rotated 180°)!

Tags: arduino-nano, power, bootloader, electronics, pcb-design

I've Made A PCB Which Includes An Arduino Nano. I Soldered Some Female Pin Headers Instead Of Soldering The Arduino Itself, So That I Can Easily Plug/Unplug The Arduino Board.

It Was All Good, ***Until*** I Accidentally Plugged The Arduino Nano Rotated 180°, Which Made Arduino Pin(12) Connected To The Vin(11.1v) At The PCB, And Arduino (Tx) Pin Plugged Into Pin(13)'s Place At PCB, And So On ...

The PCB's Power Was On (11.1v @ VIN Place At The PCB).

Now,

- When I Power The Arduino Board It Looks Normal, 5v Pin And Vin Pin Works Good, No Power Issues, But The  Arduino IDE doesn't Upload Any Sketches To It, It Gives Me This Error:

```
avrdude: stk500_recv(): programmer is not responding
avrdude: stk500_getsync() attempt 1 of 10: not in sync: resp=0x00
```

- I Tried Burning Bootloader With The IDE It Gave Me This:

```
avrdude: error: program enable: target doesn't answer. 1 
avrdude: initialization failed, rc=-1
         Double check connections and try again, or use -F to override
         this check.

Error while burning bootloader.
```

- I Tried To Upload Code With The IDE But Used USBsp Programmer, It Gave Me This:

```
avrdude: error: program enable: target doesn't answer. 1 
avrdude: initialization failed, rc=-1
         Double check connections and try again, or use -F to override
         this check.

the selected serial port 
 does not exist or your board is not connected
```

- I Tried To Program The Board Using USBasp Programmer -with ICSP pins- and avrdude, It Gave Me This:

```
avrdude: error: program enable: target doesn't answer. 1 
avrdude: initialization failed, rc=-1
         Double check connections and try again, or use -F to override
         this check.
```

- I Also Tried To Upload Code, Or Burn Bootloader Using Another Arduino, But Didn't Work!
- But When I Connect It To The Computer Using The Usb Cable, The IDE Detects It, And It Allows Me To Open The Serial Monitor!

***So, What's The Problem? Is It Completely Broken, Or It Can Be Repaired??***

I Suppose That The Atmega Is Burnt, As 11.1v Was On Pin(12), And Pin(11) Was Connected To Ground!!

Comment: Did you check with another Arduino that your circuit works in principle? Most probably you bricked your Nano.

Comment: ya, The Circuit Works Fine, I Tested It With Another Arduino ..

Comment: So your Nano is dead.

Comment: Fine  ...

Answer (score 0):

Apparently your Nano is dead.

Depending on the specific device and your skills, you can try to replace the AVR on it. Please be aware that you need to flash the bootloader on it.

Comment: Buying A New One Is Easier Than Replacing Replacing The Atmega328p! ..

Comment: Well, then go ahead. ;-) Time is money under certain circumstances, but not necessarily at hobbyists. -- BTW, please reconsider your style to write any word capitalized.

Comment: I Will  ...

Comment: As a new user of SE/Arduino your might want to take the [tour] to learn how this site works. It is not a forum. -- For example, if you think an answer solves your issue, you mark it. This way your question will be shown prominently as "solved", you saw this probably already on the list, where the answers marker is colored and check-marked. Never edit the title to add something manually.